# Query dimension / fact table ID on SSAS

Tags: ssas, system-information, dmv

I have SSAS server with a analytical tabular model. It has several dimensions and fact tables.

I want to create dynamic XMLA code for processing dimensions / fact tables. Using SSMS, I can script out sample XMLA as follows:

```
<Process xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
  <Object>
    <DatabaseID>DB1</DatabaseID>
    <DimensionID>FactTable1_cd8ad531-34f1-42df-b34e-a535eed297c1</DimensionID>
  </Object>
</Process>
```

Where do I find the DatabaseID / DimensionID information of the model on SSAS so I can use it for purpose of dynamic script? Is there any DMVs (or similar) that would return me such information?

Comment: What tool or programming language is creating the dynamic XMLA? If you say T-SQL and linked servers my answer will be different than if you say SSIS and a C# script task.

Comment: I would use SSIS, but if the solution with T-SQL & linked servers would be more elegant, I would consider using that one. Could you maybe share both?

Answer (score 0):

Create an Analysis Services connection manager in SSIS. Then create a new C# script task in SSIS and add a reference to AMO (Microsoft.AnalysisServices). I usually do that by choosing Add Reference... Browse... then pasting "C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.AnalysisServices\" then looking for the version that will be installed on the server where I will deploy this SSIS package. Then add "using Microsoft.AnalysisServices;" to the top of your code. Here's the Main() function:

```
public void Main()
{
    // Get Server and Database name from DTS connection object
    string sServer = "";
    string sDatabase = "";
    foreach (ConnectionManager oConn in this.Dts.Connections)
    {
        if (oConn.CreationName.StartsWith("MSOLAP"))
        {
            sServer = (string)oConn.Properties["ServerName"].GetValue(oConn);
            sDatabase = (string)oConn.Properties["InitialCatalog"].GetValue(oConn);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sServer) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(sDatabase))
    {
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        throw new Exception("Could not find or parse the SSAS connection string");
    }

    Server oServer = new Server();
    oServer.Connect(sServer);

    Database oDB = oServer.Databases.FindByName(sDatabase);
    if (oDB == null)
    {
        oServer.Disconnect();
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        throw new Exception("Did not find expected SSAS database: " + sDatabase);
    }

    Dimension dim = oDB.Dimensions.GetByName("Employee");
    string sDimensionID = dim.ID;
    string sDatabaseID = oDB.ID;

    MessageBox.Show(sDatabaseID + " - " + sDimensionID);

    oServer.Disconnect();

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Incidentally, I would recommend not mucking with building XMLA. Just use AMO to do the processing:

```
dim.Process(ProcessType.ProcessFull);
```

I don't know how to get the Database ID cleanly with a DMV against SSAS Tabular other than by shredding a bunch of XML. So I wouldn't recommend a linked server.